# Spring Boot 1.4: LocalDateTime mapped to varbinary instead of timestamp type

Tags: spring-boot, hsqldb, hibernate-5.x

I am using `Java 8`, `Spring Boot 1.4` and `hsqldb`.
I have an entity with `java.time.LocalDateTime` field.
When I check sql generated by hibernate, it is using `varbinary` as data type.
How do I make it use `timestamp` data type?

**Update:**
It does work when I add `hibernate-java8 (5.1.0.Final)` dependency. 
But it does not work with `hibernate-java8 (5.2.x versions)`. This might be because `Java 8` support was added to `hibernate-core 5.2` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works when `hibernate-java8 (5.1.0.Final)` dependency is added. 
It DOES NOT work with `hibernate-java8 (5.2.x versions)`. 
This is because Java 8 support was added `to hibernate-core 5.2` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to annotate your entity localDateTime_field with a converter.

```
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime localDateTime_field;
```

Here is how it goes:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Converter
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return localDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp timestamp) {
        return timestamp == null ? null : timestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```